# Fire CheckedChanged in gridview by clicking anywhere in gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'd like the CheckedChanged event for the checkbox in my gridview row to fire when clicking anywhere in the gridview row. So far, I've gotten as far as this...

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(checkbox, "")); (in the gridview RowDataBound event handler)
```

The problem is that the postback occurs but the event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code with following:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').checked = !document.getElementById('{0}').checked; {1}", checkbox.ClientID, ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(checkbox, "")));
```

I suppose, that CheckBox control checking previous state on postback and if it the same as before, the RaisePostBackEvent method not fired.